# Serialize an ajax array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, serialization

I have an array make from some input value get with jQuery like this

```
var ingredient = [];
text.each(function(){
    ingredient.push($(this).val());
});
```

and send with ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update_recipe.php",
    type: "post",
    data: ingredient,
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(code_html, statut){
        console.log(code_html);
        console.log(statut);
    },
    error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
        console.log("La requête n'a pas aboutie...");
        console.log(resultat);
        console.log(statut);
        console.log(erreur);
    }
    });
```

but when i need to get the array with php, $_POST is NULL...
Do you have an idea of how can i send this array ?

thanks

Comment: Show your php code, check value of `ingredient` with `console.log`

Comment: console.log of array is like ["2 oeufs", "125 g de farine", "25 cl de lait", "1/2 cuillÃ¨re Ã  cafÃ© de sucre", "1 cc de levure chimique", "30 g de beurre fondu", "1/2 cc de sel", "1 cs d'eau de fleur d'oranger"]

And php is just var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query string having "key=value" pairs where "key" is the `name` attribute value of the element, instead of pushing only value to an array.

```
var ingredient = "";

text.each(function(i) {
    ingredient += this.name + "=" + this.value + (i < text.length ? "&" : "");
});
```

Comment: It seem the string is not receive by my php script.

var_dump($_POST); display : array(0) {}

Comment: @Buck Do the input elements have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Now, yes... the correct solution is name="ingredient[]" thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

//with ajax

//JS

```
var data = $("#form :input").serializeArray();
data = JSON.stringify(data);
post_var = {'action': 'process', 'data': data };
$.ajax({.....etc
```

// PHP

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
print_r($data); // this will print out the post data as an associative array
```

Comment: no real need to sent as json, jQuery will form encode that array internally

Comment: yeah you can do it